# Bash Makefile concat array

Tags: arrays, bash, makefile, concatenation

I'm trying to glob a path for array of filenames, then do something with them and populate to a string (formatted properly). Here's the code/concept

```
13 javascripts: setup
14  i=0
15  for source in `ls ${SOURCE_DIR}/js/*.coffee | sed -e "s:^.*\/\(\w*\).coffee:\1:"`; do\
16    sources[i]="--input ${OUTPUT_DIR}/js/$$source.js";\
17    i=$(i+1);\
18    echo "Compiling coffee script: $$source.coffee";\
19    coffee -bo "${OUTPUT_DIR}/js" -c "${SOURCE_DIR}/js/$$source.coffee";\
20  done;\
21  python2 ${CLOSURE_PATH}/bin/calcdeps.py --path ${CLOSURE_PATH}/../\
22    $${sources[0]} --compiler_jar ${CLOSURE_PATH}/bin/compiler.jar\
23    --output_mode compiled > ${OUTPUT_DIR}/compiled.js;
24  echo "Cleaning ${OUTPUT_DIR}/js"
25  @rm -rf ${OUTPUT_DIR}/js
```

So, I want to join an array to a string and export it to the command starting with python2 on line `21`. The problem is that I can't even access any value inside the `sources` variable. When I replace line `21` with `echo $${sources[0]}`, it outputs the `--input output/js/main.js` which is the proper input.

What to do? Also, if you could point out any bash/Makefile guides, which aren't on `gnu.org` (long = time consuming), I'd appreciate it. I have experience with programming with few languages, but very little with bash, so at this point, it makes me laugh.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're trying to run python code, why not write the whole thing in python?

Comment: If I'm intutiting correctly what you're trying to accomplish, I don't think make files are going to work that way. (I'll be happy? to be proven wrong ;-).  Do you know about http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/pymake/ ? 'A mostly GNU-compatible python implementation of `make`', maybe that would help. Also, it's not clear, do you want to use bash by itself, which looks like what you have, or the bash code inside of a make file? Good luck.

Comment: it's just joining an array to a string, but I have problems with variable scopes, thanks for your suggestions, but I don't know python :(

Comment: If this is a bash script, what does it have to do with Make?

Comment: I think the double `$$` notation is specific to runtime variables with Makefiles, but since i'm not sure, i'm posting it here

Answer (score 0):

Try `[@]`:

```
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo "${a[1]}" # == 2
echo "${a[@]}" # == 1 2 3 4 5
```

see also: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: If I execute it on shell, it works perfectly, but it fails to do so in a Makefile: `sources=$(ls ${SOURCE_DIR}/js/*.coffee | sed -e "s:^.*\/\(\w*\).coffee:\1:"); echo ${sources[@]}; echo $${sources[@]}}; echo $${sources[@]}`

Comment: above cmd produces: `echo 

echo 

echo ${sources[@]}
` with a blank line between each echo

Answer (score 0):

> What to do?

Insert

```
    set -x;\
```

before line 15 to display the executed commands. One error (that doesn't affect `${source[0]}`) you will spot is that

```
      i=$(i+1);\
```

doesn't work as you seem to want it to; rather write

```
      i=$$((i+1));\
```

- double the dollar sign because it's in a makefile, and double the parentheses to get arithmetic expansion; or even simpler

```
      ((i=i+1));\
```

to get arithmetic evaluation.